# factor within factor summary statistical analysis in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with various stock information that I have used to create a positive, negative, or not determined sentiment with respect to a company name.  The head of this data are:

```
 head(companyReturnsNameScore)
#----------
  PERMNO     date EXCHCD SICCD TICKER     PRC   VOL       RET SHROUT companyNameSentiment        companyName
1  85814 19980831      3  5960   CTAC  6.1875 27989 -0.489691   6431       Not Determined 1 800 CONTACTS INC
2  85814 20021231      3  5960   CTAC 27.5700 97498  1.177725  11388       Not Determined 1 800 CONTACTS INC
3  85814 19990129      3  5960   CTAC 14.7500  5658 -0.180556   6275       Not Determined 1 800 CONTACTS INC
4  85814 20021031      3  5960   CTAC  9.0300 20192 -0.097000  11382       Not Determined 1 800 CONTACTS INC
5  85814 20021129      3  5960   CTAC 12.6600 15474  0.401993  12082       Not Determined 1 800 CONTACTS INC
6  85814 20070731      3  5961   CTAC 23.2400  5574 -0.009378  13619       Not Determined 1 800 CONTACTS INC
  marketCap marketCapDeclile
1  39791.81                2
2 313967.16                6
3  92556.25                4
4 102779.46                4
5 152958.12                5
6 316505.56                6
```

I am trying to perform statistical analysis by decile ranking of market cap (marketCapDecile), but within each decile rank, I want to further perform a by analysis for each sentiment factor. That means that for each decile rank, I want to see statistical output for each factor level of "positive, negative, not determined."  When I enter what I think is the correct command for a list of factors,

```
by( companyReturnsNameScore$RET, c(companyReturnsNameScore$marketCapDeclile, 
                           companyReturnsNameScore$companyNameSentiment), summary)
```

I unfortunately get the following error:

```
Error in tapply(seq_len(1785812L), list(`c(companyReturnsNameScore$marketCapDeclile, companyReturnsNameScore$companyNameSentiment)` = c(2L, 
   : arguments must have same length
```

I have 10 factor levels for the market cap decile, and three for the sentiment factor classification, so essentially, I want 30 analyses performed...  Problem is, I am having difficulty performing that factor within factor analysis.

What am I doing incorrectly?  How can I perform a factor within factor analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You second argument concatenates two vectors, making them twice as long as the first argument:

```
  length( c( factor(1:5), factor(6:10) ) )
[1] 10
```

You have (at least) two choices: either use a `list` (noting that the help function for `?by` says to use a list, or use the `interaction` function which returns a single vector of the length of the longest input:

```
 # 1
 by( companyReturnsNameScore$RET, 
      list( companyReturnsNameScore$marketCapDeclile, 
                       companyReturnsNameScore$companyNameSentiment),
      summary)
 # 2
 by( companyReturnsNameScore$RET, 
        interaction( companyReturnsNameScore$marketCapDeclile, 
                       companyReturnsNameScore$companyNameSentiment), 
        summary)
```

Comment: Thanks @42 for that. I thought the 'list' might work, but when I tried it, I received an error. It now works, so I must have typed something incorrectly when I submitted it originally.

Comment: Also, thanks for the 'edit' of my post so that the formatting of the question was more clearly seen.  I have been trying to make my posts cleaner, but haven't figured how to yet.  How did you get my post in such a nice format?

Comment: I just used carriage returns and a lot of extra spaces. When I edit, I try to indent items of hte same level of function parameters at similar levels. I kind of violated my own rule herebecause I should have lined up the two inner "company ..." values on my own posting. My goal is to have the code readable without needing to scroll sideways.